# Silverlight Error: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have Installed VS-2012 Express Edition. Now, I am trying to create Silverlight Application.

In the very beginning I was ended with the following error:

**You need to install the latest Silverlight Developer runtime before creating a Silverlight project.
Download the x86 runtime at:
go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=229323**

Hence, I have downloaded Silverlight Developer runtime from the above given URL and I have tried to create the Silverlight Application once again.

As and I click on the **OK** button on **New Project** dialog I am getting the following error.

What could be the reason? Can anybody please suggest what is the solution?

[image]

The error summary is below:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
>   Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.WaitForCompletion(NestedCallContext nestedCallContext, BlockingCall call, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalOutSynchronous(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, WaitHandle aborted, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalOut(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, WaitHandle aborted, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalOut[TValue](RemoteHandle`1 targetObject, Action action, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalOut[TResult,TValue](RemoteHandle`1 targetObject, Func`2 func, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.CreateDesignerImpl(IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor, RemoteCancellationToken remoteCancelToken)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass12.<Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IDesignerService.CreateDesigner>b__11(RemoteCancellationToken remoteToken)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.CallWithCancellation[TResult](CancellationToken cancelToken, Func`2 func)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor, CancellationToken cancelToken)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken cancelToken)
>
> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
>   Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>
> Server stack trace: 
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.WaitForCompletion(NestedCallContext nestedCallContext, BlockingCall call, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalIn(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalIn(IRemoteObject targetObject, Action action)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalIn[TResult](IRemoteObject targetObject, Func`1 func)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IRemoteHostSourceItem remoteItem, IRemoteHostTextEditor remoteEditor, IRemoteCancellationToken remoteToken)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IRemoteHostSourceItem remoteItem, IRemoteHostTextEditor remoteEditor, IRemoteCancellationToken cancelToken)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass8.b__6(IRemoteDesignerService d)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.<>c__DisplayClass4`2.b__3()
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()
>
> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException
>   Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>      at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>      at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
>      at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>      at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
>      at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Object[] args)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.PlatformLoader.CreatePlatformCreator(IPlatformService platformService, String assemblyFile, String typeName)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.PlatformLoader.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__1()
>      at Microsoft.Expression.Platform.PlatformService.PlatformEntry.get_PlatformCreator()
>      at Microsoft.Expression.Platform.PlatformService.GetPlatformCreator(String frameworkSpec)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.Platform.PlatformService.IsCompatibleFramework(FrameworkName hostFramework, FrameworkName guestFramework)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Project.ProjectContextManager.GetProjectContext(IHostProject project, IPlatform platform, Boolean create)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.Project.ProjectContextManager.GetSourceItemContext(IHostSourceItem sourceItem)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.DesignerService.CreateDesigner(IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor, CancellationToken cancelToken)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass10.<>c__DisplayClass12.b__f(CancellationToken cancelToken)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.CallWithCancellation[TResult](IRemoteCancellationToken remoteToken, Func`2 func)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass10.<Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner>b__e()
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.<>c__DisplayClass16`1.b__15()
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()
>
> System.NotSupportedException
>   Could not find Microsoft Silverlight SDK 5.0. Please make sure that the correct version of the Microsoft Silverlight SDK has been installed.
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.WaitForCompletion(NestedCallContext nestedCallContext, BlockingCall call, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalOutSynchronous(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, WaitHandle aborted, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalOut(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId, WaitHandle aborted, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalOut[TValue](RemoteHandle`1 targetObject, Action action, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalOut[TResult,TValue](RemoteHandle`1 targetObject, Func`1 func, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteWrapper`1.Invoke[T](Func`2 action)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteHostPlatformService.Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IHostPlatformService.GetProperty(String frameworkSpec, String propertyName)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignSurface.PlatformContext.GetProperty(String frameworkSpec, String propertyName)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.Platform.PlatformService.GetProperty(String frameworkSpec, String propertyName)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.SilverlightPlatform.SilverlightPlatformCreator..ctor(IPlatformService platformService)
>
> System.NotSupportedException
>   Could not find Microsoft Silverlight SDK 5.0. Please make sure that the correct version of the Microsoft Silverlight SDK has been installed.
>
> Server stack trace: 
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.WaitForCompletion(NestedCallContext nestedCallContext, BlockingCall call, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalIn(Action action, Int32 targetApartmentId)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalIn(IRemoteObject targetObject, Action action)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalIn[TResult](IRemoteObject targetObject, Func`1 func)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteWrapper`1.Invoke[T](Func`2 action)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteHostPlatformService.Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IHostPlatformService.GetProperty(String frameworkSpec, String propertyName)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]: 
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.IHostPlatformService.GetProperty(String frameworkSpec, String propertyName)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteHostPlatformService.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(IHostPlatformService s)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteWrapper`1.<>c__DisplayClass4`1.b__3()
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.<>c__DisplayClass7`2.b__6()
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()
>
> System.NotSupportedException
>   Could not find Microsoft Silverlight SDK 5.0. Please make sure that the correct version of the Microsoft Silverlight SDK has been installed.
>      at Microsoft.Expression.HostUtility.Platform.SilverlightDomainFactory.get_ReferenceAssembliesPath()
>      at Microsoft.Expression.HostUtility.Platform.HostPlatformService.GetProperty(String frameworkSpec, String propertyName)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteHostPlatformService.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(IHostPlatformService s)
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteWrapper`1.<>c__DisplayClass4`1.b__3()
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.<>c__DisplayClass16`1.b__15()
>      at Microsoft.Expression.DesignHost.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()

Comment: You've got something dodgy in your XAML which has caused the designer to spit chunks. Can you post the rest of your XAML? The scrollbar in the image indicates you've got some more below the grid.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Slugster. Whatever the code is available in the screen-shot is full code only except one more line. Hence, the last line is:
</UserControl>

Actually, I have NOT written any code in the XAML. Whatever you are seeing is the designer generated code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was inspired by slugster and I also started to scan the complete error message. I found that Microsoft® Silverlight® 5 SDK needs to be installed. I have installed the same from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=28359), and my problem is got sorted-out.

Answer (score 7):

After formatting your error message I see that your problem is that you also need to install the Silverlight 5 tools, which you can find on this page: [Silverlight.net downloads page](http://www.silverlight.net/downloads).

Comment: Hi Slugster,
Thank you very much for your reply.
I am working on Visual Web Developer 2012 Express. Do we need Silverlight 5 tools for *Visual Web Developer2012 Express* also?
[This post](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/256578.aspx/1) suggested that NOT required.
I am also not getting any URL to install Silverlight 5 tools for Visual Web Developer 2012 Express.
If I really need to install, can you please give me some proper link!

The link you have given now _does NOT contain Silverlight 5 tools for Visual Web Developer 2012 Express_.